# How to mock an import class used in the class I want to test?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs, vue-test-utils

How can I mock an import class used in the class I want to test?

My code looks like:

**Bird.js**

```js
export default class Bird {
  constructor() {...}
  tweet() {...}
}
```

**Nest.js**

```js
import Bird from 'Bird.js'
export default class Nest {
  spawn() {
    this.bird = new Bird()
    this.bird.tweet()
  }
}
```

I want to test that whether `spawn` could really call `tweet`, so I want to mock the whole `Bird` class. I tried:

**Nest.spec.js**

```js
jest.mock('<some_path>/Bird.js')
import Nest from '<some_path>/Nest.js'
test('...', () => {
  const nest = new Nest()
  nest.spawn()
  expect(this.bird.tweet).toBeCalledTimes(1)
})
```

However, `Nest.spawn()` invokes `this.bird.tweet()`, but it seems that `jest.mock('<some_path>/Bird.js')` doesn't affect `import Bird from 'Bird.js'` in `Nest.js`.

That is to say, it still imports the original class, and `tweet` has the original behavior instead  of a `jest.fn()`.

Answer (score 0):

As a practice that I'm following, it is a bad practice to mock your implementations, because when you will change the implementation of **Bird** your tests of **Nest** will not break, cause they using your mocked version.

A better approach would be to test the side effect of tweet. (You can think about the question: "what should happen when nest is spawn -> it should do what tweet does). With this approach you are not testing how "what tweet does" happens (by calling `tweet`) but what happens when you spawn.

It is a bit abstract explanation, I will try to explain with an example:

Let's assume that `tweet` is making a sound (which is our side effect that defined by our product, making a sound = `console.log('twit....')`), So my test will look like:

```js
import Nest from '<some_path>/Nest.js'
test('...', () => {
  jest.spyOn(console, 'log');
  const nest = new Nest()
  nest.spawn()
  expect(console.log).toBeCalledWith('twit....');
})
```

I don't care how the side effect occurs. This allows your tests to be more robust for future changes. In addition it removes the need to manage a mock implementation for your real ones.

Just test your side effects :]